# how to use the text box to change a frame in AS3

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript-3

So I am making a little game. Numbers count up and when they reach another number i want then to change the frame. E.G. the numbers start counting and when they reach say 10 it will change to frame 20. BTW this is in action-script 3

Answer (score 0):

In your document class, create a [set](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#set)ter function that will go to the frame when a certain condition is met.

```
private var _counter:uint = 0;

public function get counter ():uint
{
    return _counter;
}

public function set counter (value:uint):void
{
    if (value == _counter) return;

    _counter = value;
    if(_counter == 10) gotoAndStop(20); 
}
```

Now simply use `counter` as if it was a real variable:

```
counter += 5;
trace(counter);
counter = 10;
```

Just to be clear: you should not have the counter variable in the text field only. The Textfield is just a way to display it. You should always have a real number variable, because the `TextField` is made for `String`s, not numbers. If you want to display the counter variable in a `TextField`, do this in the set function as well:

```
public function set counter (value:uint):void
{
    if (value == _counter) return;

    _counter = value;

    textField.text = _counter.toString(); //display counter in text

    if(_counter == 10) gotoAndStop(20); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter:int = parseInt(yourTextField.text);
if(counter == 10)
{
   gotoAndStop(20);
}
```

Please note above code should be inside either an ENTER_FRAME event or TEXTField CHANGE event.  Ideally through textfield events.